# Every time I use expo client, my http network fails to work

Tags: http, visual-studio-code, tcp, expo, windows-subsystem-for-linux

TCP connections work fine as I am able to converse with someone over zoom and teamviewer. However, whenever I attempt to access another webpage, I get a network error. Google seems to work fine for some reason but any webpage I go to listed by Google fails to connect. The only way I can open up my http connections is by ending a task called "init" inside of task manager. This shuts down my vscode as well as my ubuntu terminals I have running. If someone knows the solution please do tell. It's really annoying having to close out my vscode and terminals as well as my local servers to look up information and debug.

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix to this issue.
So I was running a Windows Subsystem for Linux and my Windows Build was outdated as well as WSL. When I updated Windows and upgraded to WSL2, my issue was resolved and I don't seem to get any more network errors.